# How to determine where an environment variable came from?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a Linux instance that I set up some time ago.  When I fire it up and log in as `root` there are some environment variables that I set up but I can't remember or find where they came from.

- I've checked `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/.bash_rc`, and all the startup
  scripts.
- I've run `find` and `grep` to no avail.

I feel like I must be forgetting to look in some place obvious. Is there a trick for figuring this out?

Comment: `/etc/environment` is another one.

Comment: And `/etc/env.d/*` files. But doing `grep -R "YOUR_VARIABLE" /etc/` is probably the best way to find out.

Comment: On Mac OS X, see also [How do I find where an environmental variable got set?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51735/how-do-i-find-where-an-environmental-variable-got-set)

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz the simplest way... if variable is indeed located somewhere under /etc/ (like in my case); if you post it as answer, I would upvote ;)

Comment: In macos, /etc/env* do not exist. The answer in the macos comment also does not work. I will add macos as an additional tag to this question

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you use the `env` command to display the variables, they should show up roughly in the order in which they were created.  You can use this as a guide to if they were set by the system very early in the boot, or by a later .profile or other configuration file.  In my experience, the `set` and `export` commands will sort their variables by alphabetical order, so that listing isn't as useful.

Comment: That's great... except I'm trying to find out what's *clearing* an environment variable (set in /etc/environment). :-) (And yes, it's being set initially... I'm adding lines in scripts in various to log where it gets cleared...)

Comment: this doesn't answer his question. he doesn't want to know the value of the enviornmental variable, he wants to know the location of the configuration file the shell is referencing to get that environmental variable.

Answer (score 280):

If `zsh` is your login shell:

```
zsh -xl
```

With `bash`:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

That will simulate a login shell and show everything that is done (except in areas where stderr is redirected with `zsh`) along with the name of the file currently being interpreted.

So all you need to do is look for the name of your environment variable in that output. (you can use the `script` command to help you store the whole shell session output, or for the `bash` approach, use `7> file.log` instead of `7>&2` to store the `xtrace` output to `file.log` instead of on the terminal).

If your variable is not in there, then probably the shell inherited it on startup, so it was set before like in PAM configuration, in `~/.ssh/environment`, or things read upon your X11 session startup (`~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession`) or set upon the service definition that started your login manager or even earlier in some boot script. Then a `find /etc -type f -exec grep -Fw THE_VAR {} +` may help.

Comment: Impressive and helpful, thank you.  For us n00bs, would you explain a bit more about the mode and how do we get out of the mode this puts us in?  For example, we cannot simply pipe grep this output.

Comment: @GeoffreyHale if you `zsh -xl 2>&1` , i.e. merge the stderr and stdout ouputs, you can grep as usual.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the `fish` shell?

Comment: Even if I use `zsh -xl 2>&1`, somehow I can't grep normally. Apparently the output does not contain proper newlines or something.

Comment: I think you could just use `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>/tmp/$(uuidgen)`, then grep on that random file as well.

Comment: Fantastic masterly possession of bash

Comment: wow, I'm impressed.

Comment: Comparing *bash* environment when running with `BASH_XTRACEFD`... I find the lack of resemblance between *$PATH*s disturbing [*ventilator breaths*].

Comment: This should definitely be the right answer

Comment: Of course. This is so obvious, esp the '7'. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work on Mac OSx?  I've tried to write the out to `file.log` as you suggested, but it doesn't look like BASH_XTRACEFD is available to me.

Comment: very interesting ! is there an equivalent for tsch instead of bash ?

Comment: Do you know how are some environment variables such as `DISPLAY` set? Because I used `grep` to find this variable but I did not found any file which sets this variable. And this one is actually set because if I type in a shell `echo $DISPLAY` I can get: `:0` but I don't understand how `DISPLAY` obtains that value

Answer (score 120):

Some places to look first:

**System wide**

- `/etc/environment`: specifically meant for environment variables
- `/etc/env.d/*`: environment variables, split in multiple files
- `/etc/profile`: all types of initialization scripts
- `/etc/profile.d/*`: initialization scripts
- `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`: meant for functions and aliases

**User specific**

- `~/.profile`: used for all shells
- `~/.pam_environment`: part of Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux
- `~/.bash_profile`: initialization for login (bash-)shells
- `~/.bashrc`: initialization for all interactive (bash-)shells
- `~/.cshrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.tcshrc`: similar for non-bash shells

Comment: This is comprehensive!

Comment: Also check `~/.pam_environment` if on Ubuntu as this is the [recommended location](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.pam_environment) for storing user environment variables.

Comment: `~/.pam_environment` was it, still set from back when I used Ubuntu, and now activated under Linux Mint

Answer (score 51):

@Cian is correct. Other than using `find` and `grep`, there isn't much you can do to discover where it came from. Knowing that it is indeed an environment variable, I would attempt focusing your search in /etc/ and your home directory. Replace `VARIABLE` with the appropriate variable you're searching for:

`$ grep -r VARIABLE /etc/*`

`$ grep -r VARIABLE ~/.*`

Comment: It's surprising that an answer that says 'you can't', surrounded by answers saying 'yes you can', has even this many upvotes.

Comment: I don't see any answers that actually give a way to determine WHERE a variable was set.  There are some useful clues, but no one-liner that can do the job.

Comment: This thing solved my time. Thanx.

Comment: @MichaelScheper "you can't" do it without find/grep. later in "you can" it's described how to do it USING grep

Comment: I tried changing it using sudo. It won't change for some reason. Even after I do echo varname, it still shows the old version.

Answer (score 27):

If you put `set -x` in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, all subsequent shell commands will be logged to standard error and you can see if one of them sets these variables. You can put `set -x` at the top of `/etc/profile` to trace it as well. The output can be very verbose, so you might want to redirect it to a file with something like `exec 2>/tmp/profile.log`.

If your system uses PAM, look for `pam_env` load requests in `/etc/pam.conf` or `/etc/pam.d/*`. This module loads environment variables from the specified files, or from a system default if no file is specified (`/etc/environment` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` on Debian and Ubuntu). Another file with environment variable definitions on Linux is `/etc/login.defs` (look for lines beginning with `ENV_`).

Answer (score 8):

For `zsh` users, tracing the files that are accessed (during startup) can be useful, they are not too many and one can look through them one-by-one to find where something was defined.

```
zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE
```

Answer (score 5):

Check your startup scripts for files that *they* source using `.` (dot) or `source`. Those files could be in other directories besides `/etc` and `$HOME`.

Answer (score -1):

environment variables are stored in /etc/profile file so do 
more /etc/profile and just check for env variables you want
and if /etc/profile is not present then lokk for .profile file in your home directory

Comment: Environment variables are **not** stored in `/etc/profile`, you can define them there system wide for e.g. `bash` when used as a login shell. They are stored by the shell process after reading in definitions from files and/or commandline.