# Way to determine where certain global parameter is configured

Tags: bash, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine where an environment variable came from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from)

I wonder if there is a way to determine the location of the file where certain configuration exists. For example know that I have a global parameter `TMOUT` and I want to change it, but I don't know WHERE it is configured. I'm aware of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) question which already was asked here, however I'd like to know if there any other way available except investigating the order of variables appearance according to the `env` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will take a long time to run (since it will examine every file in the system) but it should find the file:

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -w 'TMOUT=' /dev/null
```

An alternative approach is to find out under what circumstances it is set, for example by checking whether it is set when the shell is not a login shell (`env -i bash`) and whether it is (`env -i bash --login`).  You could manually check files in `$HOME`, for example `.profile`, `.env`, `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.   There are also some files in `/etc/` which specify environment variables; it could be set in any one of them.

If your login shell is `ksh`, you will find that `$TMOUT` is set by the ksh shell itself.

---

**Edit:** to explain some of the less obvious features of the command line above:

The idiom `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` is quite common.   The point of using `-print0` instead of the default `-print` is that the file names are terminated with an ASCII NUL in the case of `-print0`.   This means that filenames containing an actual newline will be correctly represented.   Passing the `-0` option to `xargs` simply makes `xargs` understand the same convention.

The practice of routinely passing `/dev/null` as the first argument to `grep` is also worth explaining.   Since you only get end-of-file when reading from `/dev/null`,  it will never match any non-empty string with `grep`.   Hence there will be no hits for that file.   We only specify it on the grep command line to cope correctly with the case where the final time `xargs` runs grep, there is only one remaining file to be searched.    If grep has only one file argument, it lists the hits without specifying the command line.   Like so:

```
~/tmp/t$ echo hello > a
~/tmp/t$ echo hi > b
~/tmp/t$ grep '^h.*' a
hello
~/tmp/t$ grep '^h.*' a b
a:hello
b:hi
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain the command line you proposed? Especially the `-print0`, `xargs -0` and `/dev/null` in the end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an exact answer for your question it may answer a portion of it.

[StackOverflow: Linux: where are environment variables stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532155/linux-where-are-environment-variables-stored)

**EDIT:**

When debugging my shell scripts I typically add -x `#!/bin/bash -x`
You can also try running it from the shell as `bash -x`

`# su - test`

```
    test$ bash -x
     unset a r
    + . /etc/bash_completion.d/yast2-completion.sh
       **(file sourced)**
    ++ YAST=/sbin/yast
    ++ YAST_MODLIST=()
       **(variables set from file)**
       #....
    ++ /usr/bin/dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS
    + eval 'LS_COLORS='\''no=00
       #....
```