# How can I find a rogue alias declaration?

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I'm trying to find where a specific `alias` has been declared. I've searched all the usual places I know to look for aliases:

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/profile

With no luck.

I know it's an `alias` because when I do `which COMMAND`, I get:

```
alias COMMAND='/path/to/command'
    /path/to/command
```

Is there a way to find what file declares an `alias` only knowing the `alias` name?

Comment: A [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) about environment variables instead of aliases.  Basically, there is no easy way since the alias could have been set anywhere.   Try putting `set -x` as suggested at the top of your and see if that narrows it down for you.

Comment: You'd have to put `set -x` at the top of `/etc/bash_profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.  Why not just run `bash -i -x` or `bash -l -x`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would look in `/etc/profile.d/` for the offending `alias`.

You could also do the following to find it:

```
grep -r '^alias COMMAND' /etc
```

This will recursively `grep` through files looking for a line beginning with `alias COMMAND`.

If all else fails, put this at the end of your `~/.bashrc`

```
unalias COMMAND
```

Comment: When looking for rouge aliases, you should run `/bin/grep`

Comment: @JonasStein Why?

Comment: @drkvogel because grep could already be an offending alias

Answer (score 30):

There's a few things you can try:

1. use `bash -v` to see what lines are being read during shell startup
2. use `bash -x` to see what commands are being run during shell startup
3. run with only one startup file

**bash -v**

The `-v`  option makes `bash` print each line from every script file it reads as it reads it.

Start by running

```
bash -i -v >bash-i.out 2>&1
```

wait 5-10 seconds, then press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

This will give you a single file called `bash-i.out` that is like all your startup files merged (or concatenated) together.

Then use `less` to open the file and search for the alias using `/aliasname`.

Now, compare where that alias appears in relation to other lines in the file.  For example, on most systems, `/etc/bash.bashrc` has a comment at the top that says `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` has one too.

If it's above the top of your `~/.bashrc`, then it's probably a startup file in `/etc` that's defining the alias, otherwise it's in your `~/.bashrc` or a file it's including via `source` or `.` (dot command).

If that doesn't show the alias, try

```
bash -l -v >bash-l.out 2>&1
```

That tells bash to be a login shell, which reads some different startup files, for example `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

**bash -x**

If `bash -v` doesn't give you a definite answer, try running `bash -x`, which prints the commands the shell is running, rather than the lines your shell is reading.

The method is basically the same as the above except change `-v` to `-x`.  (You can use both together if necessary.)

**Run with only one startup file**

```
bash -i --rcfile="$HOME/.bashrc"
```

and see if you have the alias.

Try the same with `rcfile` set to `/etc/bash.bashrc` if your system has it.

Then try

```
bash -l --rcfile="$HOME/.bash_profile"
```

and do the same with every bash startup file that has `profile` in its name, e.g. change `$HOME/.bash_profile` to `/etc/profile`.

Whichever way makes the alias appear tells you the file you should start looking at.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `.xinitrc`? You should also check to see if your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` source any other files in them. For example, I keep all my aliases in a separate file referenced by this command:

```
[ -f ~/.bash_alias ] && source $HOME/.bash_alias
```

Some questions which might also help: Is this for a regular or root user? Which command is it? What flavour of Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the very common practice of putting my alias definitions into

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

and then calling that from .bashrc with

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && source $HOME/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: can i guess that you mean .bash_aliases in your second command instead of .bash_alias?