# How to find where is $JAVA_HOME set?

Tags: environment-variables, java

I'm trying to change the value of $JAVA_HOME & I just can't seem to find in which file is it being set currently. I can't remember where did I set it the last time. 
Already tried [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) but I need(ed) a list of files where the variable can be set.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You didn't specify a shell.  So, I will assume `bash`.  The next issue is: did you set it for your user only or system-wide?  If you set it for your user only, then run:

```
grep JAVA_HOME  ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc
```

If you set it system-wide, then it may vary with distribution but try:

```
grep JAVA_HOME /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile.d/* /etc/profile
```

If the above give no answer, you can cast a wider net:

```
grep -r JAVA_HOME /etc
grep -r JAVA_HOME ~/
```

See also the suggestions in [How to determine where an environment variable came from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from).

Comment: Thank you for responding. Couldn't find this variable in any of these files. Btw, I'm on Ubuntu (if that matters)

Comment: For clues, please check (a) if you log in as a different user, is JAVA_HOME still set? (b) If you reboot, is it still set?  This search can be complicated because any of the files I listed can source other files of their choosing and JAVA_HOME could be set in any of those.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I had set it in ~/.bashsrc but the changes didn't show up since I used different terminal instances to set & test the value of variables. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

With `zsh`:

```
zsh -xl
```

In `bash`:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

That will simulate a login shell and show everything that is done (except in areas where stderr is redirected with `zsh`) along with the name of the file currently being interpreted.

So all you need to do is look for `JAVA_HOME` in that output. (you can use the `script` command to help you store that output).