# Magic environment variables in gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gnome-terminal

I had installed a proxy software (cntlm) on my machine. It sets the environment variable http_proxy to `127.0.0.1:3128`. Now I've uninstalled the program using `apt-get remove cntlm`.

However I'm able to see the http_proxy variable:

> env | grep proxy

Gives me:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
no_proxy=127.0.0.1, localhost
```

I've tried doing a recursive grep on `~` and `/etc` but it doesn't show anything:

```
grep -ri https_proxy ~
grep -ri https_proxy /etc
```

The interesting thing is that other terminals such as LXTerminal doesn't have this problem. It only occurs in gnome-terminal.

I've also tried renaming the bash startup script files:

```
mv .bashrc .bashrc~ 
mv .profile .profile~
mv .bash_profile .bash_profile~
```

By renaming, the stuff inside these files (and any linked files) won't be sourced. However, this doesn't help either.

How do I go about debugging this problem?

I've already gone through [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/19506) and it doesn't help.

Comment: Is this happening even in a *fresh* gnome-terminal as well?

Comment: Also check the system and your *rc files for sourcing app-related scripts, not just for directly setting the env vars. Typically they're added at the end.

Comment: If you are on a gnome-based system, then also check your dconf settings, either under Settings --> Network --> Network proxy or via the terminal using `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy` fixed the problem.

There are two ways to define proxy settings:

1. Manually set the `http_proxy` environment variable in `/etc/environment` or your bash profile.
2. Define it in gnome system settings.

I had not set the environment variable manually which is why recursive grep didn't find anything. `gnome-terminal` was reading gnome system settings and automatically defining the variable.

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/150210/84445) for more details on various ways of defining proxy settings.