# How is $HOME/bin added to my path?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, fedora, path

I noticed that my path environment variable had the path for my home's binaries `$HOME/bin`.

**I did not add `$HOME/bin` directory to my path environment variable so how did `$HOME/bin` get added to the path?**

---

RE - ['possible duplicate'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from):

This question is specific to the environment variable "PATH" and is further specific to how does a specific value, i.e. `$HOME/bin`, get appended to the environment variable.

The "possible duplicate":

- does NOT mention the environment variable `PATH` anywhere in the question or answer
- does NOT mention anything about `$HOME/bin` anywhere in the question or answer

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't need to mention anything about `PATH` since it covers environment variables in general.

Answer (score 6):

on CentOS/RHEL 6.x (and up) and Fedora 20 (and up):

When you login, the script `$HOME/.bash_profile` is executed and this script adds `$HOME/bin` to your path.

on Ubuntu:

When you login, the script `$HOME/.profile` is executed and this script adds `$HOME/bin` to your path. (source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/49784/how-is-bin-added-to-my-path)

Comment: On Ubuntu `$HOME/bin` only gets added to the path when it exists so anyone adding it needs to make sure that .profile gets run again.

Answer (score 5):

This is in `/etc/skel/.profile` and consequently in all users `~/.profile` until changed.

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

---

True of Debian 6, therefore Ubuntu, and maybe others.