# How to find where an environment variable is defined?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I cannot unset the `http_proxy` permanently. Every time I open a terminal window, it is restored to `http://127.0.0.1:1080`.

I have checked `/etc/environment`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` and the scripts inside `/etc/profile.d` but find nothing about proxy.

So now I want to know how to find out where-in which file-an environment variable is defined. I mean something like `where http_proxy` and it prints `/etc/blahblah`(the path of the file that defines http_proxy).

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks! That's what I need. I have flagged my question as a duplicate.

Comment: No problem :) I have a bunch of q's like these favorited so it was easy to find.

Answer (score -2):

Just add to `.bashrc` a line with `export http_proxy="<proxy you want to use>"`. This way each time you will run a new shell, this proxy will be in use, same for https and ftp proxy

Comment: But I want to find out in which file `http_proxy` is defined, not how to define it.

Comment: In Centos this should be in /etc/bashrc, find similar file in /etc or in /usr. But as far as I know by default this variable is not set in linux, additionally you can check does new user has this variable set to the same value.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. But thanks for the information.