# Uninstall Android Studio + SDK

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, android, adb

I am using linux arch. I installed android according to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android).
I uninstalled every skd component and android studio using `pacman -Rs`. Also, I removed every hidden folder in the home directory that had something to do with android such `.android`, .`gradle`, AndroidStudio. But the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` is still set and the following command

`ps aux | grep 'adb'` returns `adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4`

Where is the environment variable ANDROID_HOME set and what means `adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4`? Is android not properly uninstalled?

The command `adb` returns `bash: adb: command not found`

EDIT:

In a */proc/pid/environ*, there are still things like 
*/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin*

Answer (score 0):

My system has android-studio, android-tools, and a few other android related packages installed. The variable `ANDROID_HOME` is not set at all. This leads me to believe that you have manually set it somewhere. Have a look in places like `.profile`, `.bashrc`, and friends. If you have no luck you could try something like `grep -r 'ANDROID_HOME' ~/` (this is not a good pattern to use due to its inefficiency). There are [better ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) to do this.

The adb command you are seeing is simply and adb server that has been forked and is thus running in the background, it is listening for TCP connections on port 5037. It is likely just something left over you have forgotten to terminate. It should be fine to just run `pkill adb` to end this process.

With all of this said, I think **it's likely that your android related packages are fully uninstalled**. you can check what android packages are installed by using `pacman -Qs android`. If you are sure you really want to purge all traces of android from your system consider running something like `sudo pacman -Rn $(pacman -Qsq android`)