# Font Rendering Change After Upgrade from Fedora 25 to 26

Tags: fedora, fonts

I did the the Upgrade f25 → f26 and was surprised by a change of the font rendering to the worse. I use the KDE spin and mostly KDE programs but some GTK programs as well.

The following is the change in GVim (GTK) with unchanged settings using “Droid Sans Mono 10” as the editor font. It is enhanced without interpolation to 4× in order to make it easier to spot. Especially the “m” and “g” are affected.

[image]

f25 on the top, f26 on the bottom.

In Konsole (KDE/Qt), a similar regression has happened:

[image]

Other fonts are affected as well, this is Thunderbird (GTK):

[image]

I am not exactly sure what has changed implicitly by the upgrade. It looks like the hinting got worse. How can I get the fonts back to the appearance that I had before?

## Update

I have created a file `/etc/profile.d/freetype2.sh` with contents:

```
export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"
```

However, this has not changed anything after a full reboot, it still appears in the new version, which I perceive as blurry.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Freetype 2.7 introduced a new rendering mode and it is used by default (more here https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/subpixel-hinting.html). To revert it add `export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35"` to `/etc/profile.d/freetype2.sh`.

Comment: I have just tried that, but that did not seem to have changed anything, as described in the update to my question. So perhaps Fedora has not compiled version 35 but only 40? This way one cannot change it?

Comment: @MartinUeding, please check if the env. variable is actually loaded `env | grep FREETYPE_PROPERTIES`

Comment: I have tried a different user account on my system, there the variable gets loaded. At least in GVim, the font looks like v35. In Konsole it looks like v40. On my main account, the environment variable is not loaded. So this might be the issue. Both sessions are KDE. Where could this variable be unloaded or skipped?

Comment: Look here for how to trace the environment changes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding the following lines in `/etc/fonts/local.conf`:

```
<match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
    <const>hintfull</const>
  </edit>
</match>
```

After logging out and logging back in, both KDE and GTK+ 3 applications use the old Truetype settings.