# RedHat/Centos6.5 Environmental Variables Set on Startup - but from where?

Tags: linux, rhel, environment-variables

I using Redhat/Centos 6.5.

I am starting up the system and it already has environment variables set and is already running processes when it starts up.

My questions:

- Where do these environment variables get set?
- Where do these processes get set and how do I know what is running?

Comment: I think the first part of your question is answered here: [How to determine where an environment variable came from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/173368).

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you login in a RedHat based distro, you will land in your home directory which by default is in `/home/user`. In that directory you will find some hidden files/scripts that are executed in order to prepare your environment and other stuff.

**Answer to question 1:**
`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are the files that load all the variables you see when you run the `printenv` or `env` command. You can see those files by running `ls -la` in your home directory.

**Answer to question 2:**
The `ps` command by itselt won't show all the process that are running, you should run `ps -ef` instead. Of course you can filter that output using `grep` command like `ps -ef|grep -i somethingtomatch` or run the `top` command.

Run `man ps` and `man top` for more info about these utilities.

Comment: @sheeple please vote up the answer or mark as correct so it could help others. Glad that helped.