# OS incorrectly switching between root and sudoer user

Tags: linux, sudo, users, root, oracle-linux

I have 3 users in my server:

1. root
2. user1
3. user2

When I try to change my current user from user1 to user2 by using the command `sudo su user1`, my operating system sometimes changes instead from user1 to root (this is verified by using the `whoami` command).

The opposite happens when I try to change my current user from user1 to root by using the command `sudo su root`, the OS sometimes changes from user1 to user2.

Some extra errors (or symptoms) detected are:

- When already logged as user2 I can't change to root user by any method (I end up restarting the server connection until it works).
- Sometimes when I am logged as either root or user2 and time passes I find that my current user has changed automatically from root to user2 or vice versa.
- The user name does not display correctly in command line when logged as root or username2 (it sometimes displays `[user1@IP ~] #` while the `whoami` command displays `root`, for example).

Comment: `sudo su user` is being used to not prompt for password (I am aware of the security implications of doing this). Anyways, if I use `su user` and introduce the password manually the exact same problem still rises. I have read the manuals you mentioned and used both options, unfortunately with no results.

The sequence of commands used is only: `sudo su user` or `su user`. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `su -l user` and `su -l root` still reproduce the issue. I have feeling that it has to do with some kind of "user aliases" or "environment variables" as you mentioned, unfortunately I haven't found related info to test it.

Comment: No, I can't think of anything more except on your use of `sudo su`: if a user can use `sudo` without a password, then `sudo -iu username` is the command to use. There really is no purpose invoking `sudo su`.

Comment: What’s the result of running `id user1` and `id user2`?

Comment: Both IDs are the same (0, which I believe belongs to root). What I have noticed is that `USER`, `LOGNAME` and `MAIL` environment variables are being overwritten from one another occasionally. 
Already tried to search for the process that generates them, with no luck.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue by exploring all environment variable definition scripts to make sure user ID were not shared. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure every user has a unique user ID, and all the environment variable definition scripts are not set to overwritte user ID.

1. Compare the outputs of `id user1` and `id user2`.
2. Check the [folders where environment variables are defined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from).
3. Edit /etc/passwd and /etc/group files if permission/ID issues show up. Make sure to read the docs of both files. Docs at: [/etc/passwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html), [/etc/group](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html)