# How to unset bash variable `!::=::\`?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When I run `printenv` one of the returned variables is `!::=::\`. I noticed that the variable exists because docker does not work correctly with it set.

```
$ printenv | grep ::
!::=::\

$ docker stack deploy keycloak -c keycloak.yml
unexpected environment "=::=::\\"
```

I am using git-bash on windows.
The strange thing is that this variable only exists when I am using *some* terminal emulators such as ConEmu, Window terminal, Git-bash terminal while it does not exist when using VSCode's builtin terminal.

Why does this variable exist, and how do I remove it?

I tried the following methods with no success:

```
$ unset !::
bash: :: unrecognized history modifier

$ unset \!::

$ unset \!\:\:

$ echo $!::
::

$ env | grep ::
!::=::\

$ printenv | grep :: | cat -A
!::=::\$

$ export !::= 
bash: :: unrecognized history modifier

$ export \!::=
bash: export: `!::=`: not a valid identifier

$ export $!::=
bash: export: `::=`: not a valid identifier

$ set +H
$ unset !::
$ unset \!::
$ env | grep ::
!::=::\
```

The following works:

```
$ env -u \!:: env | grep::

$ env -u \!:: docker stack deploy keycloack -c keycloak.yml
Creating network keycloack_default 
...
```

My environment: 
OS: `Windows` with `git-bash` (MSys based) 
Bash version: `5.2.15(1)-release`

Comment: Which OS do you use? What's your `bash` version (`echo $BASH_VERSION` or `bash --version`)?  I can't even create this variable in bash, a variable name in `bash` must begin with alphabetic character or an underscore.  Can you please also show the result of `printenv | grep :: | cat -A`? I want to see if there are some invisible characters there.

Comment: I am using git-bash on windows. 
`BASH_VERSION=5.2.15(1)-release`
`printenv | grep :: | cat -A` shows `!::=::\$`

Comment: As far as bash is concerned, this is an invalid name for an environment variable, and it doesn't provide tools to manipulate it. The best solution would be to figure out where it comes from: either it's set in Windows, or it's set by some common library that some terminal emulators use, or it's set by some buggy Windows compatibility code in the initialization of git-bash (before user init files). Investigating this requires Windows expertise and is off-topic here, I suggest [su].

Comment: I see this question was closed as a duplicate, but the answers to the duplicate question don't provide a workaround, they just explain why it happens.

Comment: The question is still a duplicate though, because the dupe does ask how to remove it

Comment: Is it really duplicate? The goal of other the question is to get an explanation, and the goal of this question is to change the behaviour.

Comment: It literally asks "how to get rid of it?"

Comment: The *question* is indeed a duplicate, but close votes say, the question already has an *answer*, while that old question didn't get an answer that explains how to get rid of it. So while this question adds nothing, the answers are worth not to be hidden by the duplicate close.

Comment: @Philippos-prostrike- that makes a case for the answers here to be merged there, not reopening, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how I solved it. I created a `.profile` file that if it identifies a variable with `::`, it starts a new bash without this variable.

```
$ cat $HOME/.profile
if env |grep -q ::
then
        exec env -u \!:: bash
fi
```

By the way, I tried to see where it comes from; The `bash` process is created by a `mintty` process whose parent is 1:

```
$ ps -p $$
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     2150    2149    2150      12536  pty1     1234897 15:34:37 /usr/bin/bash

$ ps -p 2149
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     2149       1    2149       9644  ?        1234897 15:34:37 /usr/bin/mintty
```

And this mintty process is created with this environment variable:

```
$ grep -z :: /proc/2149/environ
!::=::\
```

But since there isn't actually an init process (pid 1), I don't know how exactly this mintty process is created by `git-bash`, and why it starts with this environment variable. But anyway, the workaround above worked for me.

Comment: The variable originates from windows itself. If you launch a terminal from an existing terminal, the `!::=::\`  variable does not exist. If you launch a terminal using the UI, both git-bash (msys1) and msys2 will have the variable set.

I have posted a superuser.com question here https://superuser.com/questions/1785348/bash-terminals-launched-from-windows-ui-have-an-invalid-variable-set

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it _does_ work even if it is a workaround. Hopefully the users at superusers.com will find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why it exists, but you can unset it with `env -u`:

```
$ env | grep ::
!::=::
$ env -u \!:: bash -c 'env | grep ::'
$
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to work. I can unset it that way; but is there any way that I can make the change persistent?

Comment: Did you have this variable in the shell, or did you create it somehow?

Comment: @anderioMoga, please try `unset \!::`

Comment: As written in the original question, `unset \!::` does not work.

Comment: @anderioMoga To make it persistent, you would need to track down what creates that environment variable and prevent it from doing so.

Comment: There is one slight problem; I do not know where this variable is created. It is not consistent across different terminal emulators. And bash does not show it being created when its launched with `-x` set.

Comment: I was able to set it from Perl: `perl -lwE '$ENV{"!::"} = "::"; print "before"; system q(env | grep ::); print "after"; system q(env -u !:: bash -c "env | grep ::")'`

Comment: @anderioMoga Since that is a different question, maybe you should ask it separately. Check existing questions first though, like this one: [How to determine where an environment variable came from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813)

Comment: I know it is a different question, and I have checked that. I am confident that it is not being set by any startup profiles or scripts. `grep -r \!:: /etc/*` and `grep -I -r \!:: ~/*` do not show any results.

Comment: @Kusalananda That thread isn't relevant because here the variable is not set in shell code, it's clearly coming from some Windows thing (or a bug in some Windows-specific code in the bash port).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' That's fine, they can just ask a new question then, if it's on-topic on this site. Or on the https://superuser.com/ site if it turns out to be Windows-related.

Comment: I have discovered that the variable only exists if the terminal session is launched using the graphical windows UI. If I launch my terminal from another terminal, it does not have the magic `!::=::\` variable. So I will create a new post on superuser.com

Comment: @choroba Unfortunally, this question was closed as a duplicate, but that original question fails to answer how to unset the variable. To help future users find their answer, please add your answer to the original question, too. Thank you.